# How to deal with different sizes of sentences when giving them as input to a Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks, dimensionality-reduction, natural-language

I am giving a sentence as input to a tree structured Neural Network, where the leaf nodes will be the word vectors of the words in the sentence.

That tree will be a [binarized constituency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(linguistics))(see the binary vs n-ary branching section) parse tree.

I am trying to develop a semantic representation of the sentence.

**The problem is**, that since each sentence will have a different parse tree and different lengths, each sentence will have a different neural network. Due to this ever changing structure of neural network, I can't train it.

But this paper develops a tree structured Neural network using constituency and dependency based parse trees-

1) [Improved Semantic Representations From Tree-Structured Long Short-Term Memory Networks](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00075v3.pdf) by Kai Sheng Tai, Richard Socher, and Christopher Manning

And this paper uses CNNs to extract a semantic representation.

2) [Recurrent Continuous Translation Models](http://nal.co/papers/KalchbrennerBlunsom_EMNLP13) by Nal Kalchbrenner,and  Phil Blunsom. This picture gives a rough idea.[image: CSM]

**Possible Solution**-
I can map the sentence vector to a fixed number of neurons and then use those neurons to create a tree structure. For example if there is the sentence length is 10 and the max sentence length is 20, I can create a fixed dimensionality layer of 20 neurons and then (in this particular case) the first word to the first 2 neurons, 2nd word to the 3rd and 4th neuron and so on.
Dynamic mapping can be done based on the sentence length.

The weight matrix of the sentence layer to the fixed dimensionality layer will be fixed(the weights should be kept 1). No biases.

But I think there will be some problems in this representation- for example- If this sentence "I had a lovely icecream and a pastry for dessert." is mapped to the fixed dimensionality layer it will become "I I had had a a lovely lovely icecream icecream and and a a pastry pastry for for dessert dessert..". So that means that shorter sentences will have a more profound effect on the neural network compared to the longer sentences. This biasness towards shorter sentences should also create duplicate words in the output(of a sequence generator). Could someone correct me if I am wrong?

I would welcome more solutions, especially ones that do not remove the relationships that words have between them in a sentence.

I will be implementing this using theano and python. I am considering a layer based approach and using theano.scan to iterate over the layers to finally form the sentence representation.

Comment: Hi, use bag of words. If you have large corpus, then dimension of matrix will be huge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model

Comment: @ frankov, I can not use models that remove relationships between consecutive words

Comment: then use modification of bag of words, or change a way how you solve problem.

Comment: @frankov, I can not change the way I solve the problem. I am welcome to suggestions on how to modify the bag of words approach.

Comment: http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-alternatives-to-bag-of-words-for-analyzing-text-documents

Comment: I think that you need read about parsing sentences in NLP. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: I would go for word vectors and a Recurrent Neural Network model (LSTM, SCRNN etc.)